# Detect corrupted Indexes

Tags: postgresql, index, corruption

How to detect corrupted indexes in PostgreSQL?

When I pull data from a column with primary key attribute in a table with where condition, it brings incomplete results. Likewise, when I sort with order by in the relevant column, the data is missing. When you dump the table and press it to another database or transfer the table to another table by changing its name, the data comes back healthy. In this case I suspect the primary key is corrupt. What do I need to do to scan the whole database for corrupt primary keys.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I edited it, can you review it again?

Answer (score 3):

Run the `bt_index_parent_check` function from the [amcheck](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/amcheck.html) extension. That can detect most cases of data corruption in a given index.

Comment: thank you, i will try